# translate SQL request to JPQL request

Tags: java, jpql

I'm learning JPQL and I wonder how to translate this query into JPQL ?

I have entities `Astre` for astres table and `Planete`for planetes table. `generate_series()` is PostgreSQL function.

```
SELECT t1.galaxie, t1.ss, t1.position FROM 
(
   SELECT galaxie, ss, position FROM 
   generate_series(1, 9) galaxie 
   CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 500) ss 
   CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 15) position 
) t1
 LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.galaxie, a.ss FROM astres a 
   INNER JOIN planetes p 
   ON a.id=p.astre_id 
   WHERE p.planete_mere=TRUE 
   GROUP BY a.galaxie, a.ss 
   HAVING COUNT(*)=3 
) t2 
ON t1.galaxie = t2.galaxie 
AND t1.ss = t2.ss 
LEFT JOIN 
( 
   SELECT a.galaxie, a.ss, a.position FROM astres a 
   INNER JOIN planetes p 
   ON a.id=p.astre_id 
) t3 
ON t1.galaxie=t3.galaxie 
AND t1.ss=t3.ss 
AND t1.position=t3.position 
WHERE t2.galaxie IS NULL 
AND t3.galaxie IS NULL 
ORDER BY t1.galaxie, t1.ss, t1.position
```

I can supply entities code if needed.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can't. Use a native query.

Comment: ok Thank you but why ? Is it because I use `generate_series()` function ?

Comment: Yes, and also because of the `on` clauses, because of the subqueries in the from clause, and because of the cross joins

Comment: ok ok...we can't use subqueries with JPQL ?

Comment: You can, but not in the from clause. In the where clause, it's OK. And AFAIK, it's also OK in the select clause.

Comment: Hmm thank you JB, I will use native query so.